# From the following code, at least how many test cases are needed to guarantee 100% coverage?

Tags: testing, code-coverage

```
Input Number_of_Coins
Total=0
While Number_of_Coins > 0
Input Value_of_Coin
Total=Total + Value_of_Coin
Number_of_Coins=NUmber_of_Coins -1
End Loop
Print "Your coins are worth " & Total

3
1
4
2
```

According to me, answer is 3.

Can somebody please explain, if my answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would test the following :

1. Number of_Coins  < 0
2. Number of Coins = 1
3. Number of coins isn't a valid number
4. Number of coins > 1 and all Value_of_coin entries > 0
5. Value_of_coin one or more entry negative
6. Value_of_coin one entry not a valid number
7. Less Value_of_coin entries than Number_of_coins
8. More Value_of_coin entries than Number_of_coins

I make that at least 8 - there maybe more.

Answer (score 0):

But options given are 1-4.I think the question says atleast test cases. so it should be minimum test cases to cover 100% coverage.